# How does Spring read application yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring and I'm trying to understand the basics.

From the ground up, i know application yml is where all my properties are contained.

Such as my spring.datasource which has my db connection details and driver information.

But how does spring know about application.yml

How does it know to look under

src/main/resources/config/application.yml

I've googled but I have not found anything about this.

Comment: [boot-features-external-config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) The file is in the classpath and spring search for it

Comment: with an attitude like this (trying to understand what is really going on) you will never be able to use Spring :)

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Spring searches a specific set of locations for the application configuration file. It looks for an `application.properties` or `application.yml` file in the classpath by default, there are also profile specific variants `(application-{profile}.properties`.

Moreover, the location of the configuration file can be customized by passing command-line arguments, system properties, or environment variables to the `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your application.yaml is resolved in the same way as application.properties which is described in [boot-features-external-config-application-property-files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)